# Java basic Regular Expression: get value of both placeholders

Tags: java, regex

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("the [a-z]+ jumped over the [a-z]+ ")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    // how do I print out what jumped over what???
}
```

In this example, someone will type something like "the cow jumped over the moon" or
"the fox jumped over the dog" or "the cat jumped over the mouse" ...
I will need to be able to figure out what values they put into the two placeholders.
So my question is how do I get the values of the two [a-z]+ spots in the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use capturing groups which are marked by parantheses:  `"the ([a-z]+) jumped over the ([a-z]+)"`.

Then use `matcher.group(1)` and `matcher.group(2)` to retrieve them (group 0 is always the entire match).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a group. Try using this regex:

```
"the ([a-z]+) jumped over the ([a-z]+) "
```

Then access it using the group(int) method. Here is an example:

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/GroupInPat.html

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions groups are captured using paranthesis:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("the ([a-z]+) jumped over the ([a-z]+) ");
```

If the regexp matches, you can get the captured [group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29)s as follows:

```
String group1 = matcher.group(1);
String group2 = matcher.group(2);
```